# Story Map (Visualization of Requirements)

Tags: language-agnostic

in our company we try to establish the concept of a Story Map (Jeff Patton ) at the moment.

I have the following questions:
- What happens in a story map with cross-cutting issues/tasks? We have activities that run throughout the project. How are these activities in a story map being held?

- In a story map, there are areas of responsibility. What happens when an activity is moved from one area of the map to another but the other activities remain unchanged in the time sequence. Are the task areas 2 times in the story map, since the temporal sequence should be kept?
- Is the time sequence for each task area or the whole story map?
- Headings for task areas such as installation, termination, cancellation and change are okay? These are our business processes that are implemented.

Thanks in advance for answering the questions.

Kai.

Answer (score 0):

Kai, here are two perspectives on story mapping: [John Walpole of Twitter shares their experience with story maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svquaeyKg5E) and I also wrote [a primer on story mapping](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2016/05/guide-to-agile-user-story-maps/).